# Find the kth smallest number obtained by subtracting two element in sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a sorted array with length *n* where 1 < *n* <= 1e5, how can I find the *k*th smallest difference between two elements in the array?
For example, I have {1,4,9,16} and *k* equal 5, then I have differences {3,5,7,8,12,15} and the result is 12.
I couldn't find any solution other than finding all differences between two elements, this algorithm will take Θ(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: You only need to calculate `n*k` differences. `x[i] - x[i + k +1]` cannot be the k-th smallest differences because `x[i] - x[i+1]`, `x[i] - x[i+2]` ... `x[i] - x[i+k]` are all smaller

Comment: the problem is that k can reach to 1e9

Comment: This is probably from a "challenge" site, but in principle I think it still falls under [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I'd look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting which is fundamentally o(n^2) for the whole data set, but then look for an easier way to find the kth item. Right now, you're finding every solution and then getting the kth after the fact.

Comment: whats the question? What time complexity is required?

Comment: are the element unique? what are the bound for k ?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me how you intend to handle duplicate differences.  Consider the array `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.  Do you say that the differences are `{1, 2, 3}`?  Or would you say that they are `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}`?

If the latter, then the following code will take average time `O(n log(n))` and worst case time `O(n log(n)^2)`.  It is based on a binary search of the differences.

I am *ahem* not a C++ programmer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename my_type>
my_type kth_diff(my_type a[], int n, int k) {
    // {j, {m, n}} represents a[m] - a[j], a[m+1] - a[j], ..., a[n] - a[j]
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> diff_range;
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < n; i++) {
        diff_range.push_back({i, {i+1, n-1}});
    }

    while (0 < diff_range.size()) {
        int i = diff_range[0].first;
        int j = (diff_range[0].second.first + diff_range[0].second.second)/2;
        my_type pivot = a[j] - a[i];

        // And back up over the max values that make a pivot.
        while (0 < j && a[j-1] == a[j]) {
            j--;
        }

        int count_below = 0;
        int count_at = 0;
        vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> diff_range_low;
        vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> diff_range_high;

        vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator it;
        for (it = diff_range.begin(); it != diff_range.end(); it++) {
            i = it->first;
            j = max(it->second.first, j);
            while (j < n && a[j] - a[i] < pivot) {
                j++;
            }
            count_below += j - it->second.first;
            if (it->second.first < j) {
                // If the pivot is too small, use this.
                diff_range_low.push_back({i, {it->second.first, j-1}});
            }

            while (j < n && a[j] - a[i] == pivot) {
                j++;
                count_at++;
            }
            if (j <= it->second.second) {
                // If the pivot is too big, use this.
                diff_range_high.push_back({i, {j, it->second.second}});
            }
        }

        if (count_below + count_at <= k) {
            // We only need to count ranges past the pivot.
            diff_range = diff_range_high;
            // Keep track of the number below that are accounted for.
            k -= count_below + count_at;
        }
        else if (k < count_below) {
            // We only need to count ranges before the pivot.
            diff_range = diff_range_low;
        }
        else {
            return pivot;
        }
    }

    return a[0];
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1,4,9,16};
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    for (int k = 0; k <  n*(n-1)/2; k++) {
        cout << k << "\t" << kth_diff(a, n, k) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked and it really looks like the complexity of your approach is not dependent on k [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/sZhyvun31zJHTp2W8YpsuhnS3XY). The code also looks like it generates correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I look at this problem like this.

For `[a,b,c,d] such a<b<c<d` and `x,y,z>0 and b = a+x, c = b+y, d=c+z`, then `b-a = x`, `c-b = y`, `c-a = x+y`, `d-b = y+z`, `d-a = x+y+z`.
What does it tell us? The more apart are the elements the bigger the difference, and it adds up with every step.

It is unknown if `x<y` or `x>y` but for sure `x+y>x` and `x+y>y`, so your differences can be divided into distance classes.

`diff_1 = {d-c,c-b,b-a}`, `diff_2 = {d-b,c-a}`, `diff_3={d-a}`

now what you probably can see by now is `min(diff_1) < min(diff_2) < min(diff_3)`, so to find the second smallest difference you don't need to check for min(diff_3) because it is at best the third smallest element.

So what you do is to implement something like this pseudocode:

```
int findLeastDiff<k>(std::vector<int> v)
{
  assert(v_contains_k_distinct_elements(v));
  std::vector<int> result;
  std::sort(v.begin(),v.end()); // O(nlog(n));
  v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(),v.end()),v.end()); // O(n)
  for<<int i=1; i<=k; ++i>>
  {
     adjacent_difference<i>(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(result));// O(n-i)
  } // O(k(n-k/2)) = O(k*n)
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.begin());  // O(nlog(n));
  result.erase(std::unique(result.begin(),result.end()),result.end()); // O(n)
  return result[k];
}
```

The above is just a concept and for sure can be optimized a lot. What is the complexity? `O(nlog(n)+n+k*n+nlog(n)+n) = O((2log(n)+k+2)*n)`

It probably can be optimized with some clever way of reducing the search space by removing ranges with already too big differances.

Comment: Since `k` can be up to `n choose 2`, this is a `O(n^2)` algorithm. Also there is nothing in the problem description that suggests we can assume any kind of uniqueness.

Comment: @btilly So are all the algorithms of O(f(k,n)) - like w `std::nthelement()` or `std::partial_sort()`. The point is they are useful for k << n. That's the whole point of differentiating between k and n.

Comment: I figured out the reason for your uniqueness. And don't see how to avoid the dependence on `k`.  That said, there are lots of problems where you can locate the `k`th element without calculating the others, and therefore your speed doesn't depend on `k`.

Comment: Actually, on rereading, I don't think that the uniqueness is intended.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675310/585411 for an algorithm with no performance dependence on `k`.

Comment: "Find the kth smallest *number* obtained by..." (a value) - it denotes a uniqueness for me. If it was to allow for repeated values it'd state "find the kth smallest difference between 2 elements in the sorted array". But it doesn't matter, because whether unique or not it's just a small alteration.

Comment: Actually there is a huge performance difference.  The approach I gave is fast with non-uniqueness, but cannot be fixed for uniqueness without constructing all of the differences.  (Exactly what it tries to avoid doing.)